# Warning in .\libraries\DisplayResults.php#869 A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was create Database (products) table Items with tow columns (id,name) and I added values to this columns then this errors  display

```
Warning in .\libraries\DisplayResults.php#869
 A non-numeric value encountered

Backtrace

.\libraries\DisplayResults.php#4933: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getTableNavigation(
integer 0,
integer 0,
boolean false,
string '',
)
.\libraries\DisplayResults.php#4378: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getPlacedTableNavigations(
integer 0,
integer 0,
string 'top_direction_dropdown',
boolean false,
string '',
)
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1685: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->getTable(
,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#1976: PMA_getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
array,
boolean true,
integer 1,
integer 1,
NULL,
,
array,
)
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2199: PMA_getQueryResponseForResultsReturned(
,
array,
string 'products',
string 'items',
NULL,
NULL,
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
integer 1,
integer 1,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `items`',
NULL,
)
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2061: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'products',
string 'items',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `items`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
.\sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'products',
string 'items',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `items`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Comment: Please format the question. If the error occurs when you execute a query in phpmyadmin then please remove the php and mysqli tags.

Comment: Which phpMyadmin version? How did you add values, by using the Insert tab? What values did you insert? If you try to insert a single row as a test, does the problem still occur? Did the data get inserted despite the error or did the insert fail?

Comment: <?php

$dsn  = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=products';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>'SET NAMES utf8', 
);

try{
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass,$options);
$db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$q = "INSERT INTO items (name) VALUES ('منتج1')";
$db->exec($q);
}
 catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'faild' . $e ->getMessage();
 }

Comment: What are the data types for your columns `id` and `name`? What collation are they (if they have any)? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: phpmyadmin version 4.6.5.2
id column is integer, and name column is character

Comment: Same as  xampp-7.1.1, running on windows 10

Comment: Try version 4.8.1

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13031).

Replace from line 867:

```
    // Move to the next page or to the last one
    $endpos = $_SESSION['tmpval']['pos']
        + $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'];

    if ($this->__get('unlim_num_rows') === false // view with unknown number of rows
        || ($endpos < $this->__get('unlim_num_rows')
        && $this->__get('num_rows') >= $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows']
        && $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'] != self::ALL_ROWS)
    ) {

        $table_navigation_html
            .= $this->_getMoveForwardButtonsForTableNavigation(
                $html_sql_query, $pos_next, $is_innodb
            );

    } // end move toward
```

with

```
   // Move to the next page or to the last one
    if ($this->__get('unlim_num_rows') === false // view with unknown number of rows
        || ($_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'] != self::ALL_ROWS
        && $_SESSION['tmpval']['pos'] + $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'] < $this->__get('unlim_num_rows')
        && $this->__get('num_rows') >= $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows'])
    ) {

        $table_navigation_html
            .= $this->_getMoveForwardButtonsForTableNavigation(
                $html_sql_query, $pos_next, $is_innodb
            );

    } // end move toward
```

Comment: works. by me this was the file to edit `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/DisplayResults.php`

Answer (score 2):

Above warning messages tell that, there have an issue on 613 number of line of this file /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php

So let’s go to edit that file and reach on 613 lines.

|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)

Replace this line to

|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1

Revert back if still having any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I followed these in Ubuntu Xenial and the issue got resolved.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

Refrence:
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15515

Answer (score 1):

uncheck **Show All** checkbox above the table in **PhpMyAdmin**

:----)